# How to center a jQuery popup title?

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery popup that I am invoking like this:

```
$("#createprofilepopup").dialog( { title: 'Title text' , height: 490, width: 580 } );
```

But it appears aligned left. Is there a way to center the title?

Thanks!!

Comment: Figure out the CSS class of the element containing the title and add `.cssclass { text-align: center; }`.

Answer (score 11):

Add CSS rule:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the rule should contain ``display:block`` because it seems that the ui-dialog-title element is a span-element, therefore has by default display:inline?

Answer (score 2):

as per my understanding, if you check jquery-ui.css then you will find this line

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar{ padding:...}
```

or you can try this :

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar{
     text-align: center;
     width: 100%;}
```

play with this code and hopefully you will get the desired result. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the jQuery UI widget set, try modifying the ".ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title" set of classes to the following:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title {
    float: left;
    margin: .1em 16px .1em 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspecting the code reveals that the CSS class `.ui-dialog-title` is applied on a `<span>` element, which is [inline](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp) by default, so actually the correct CSS code should be:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this style and if it has a float:left. If yes, remove it

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title
```

Then on this style, add text-align:center

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar
```